# Validar registro ya existente en Angular

Tags: angular, vscode, frontend

Deseo realizar un nuevo Registro; pero se debe condicionar y no debe registrar si ya existe el Vendedor en Angular

````
    ```
       `submit(): void {
     debugger;
    
     if (this.form.invalid) {
     this.marcarErrores();
     } else {
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('ICodVendedor', this.form.get('iCodVendedor').value);
   
   this.postSubscription = this.preventaService.guardar(this.form.value, null).subscribe((resp: any) =>{
    
  this.limpiarControles();
  this.idPreVenta = resp;
    
  this.form.patchValue({
    iCodPreVenta: Number (this.idPreVenta.mensaje)
   });`
 ```
````

Esta es la parte del component.ts, la cuál no me está siendo ejecutada
`` `if (this.idPreVenta.mensaje != 'iCodVendedor') { Swal.fire({ icon: 'success', title: '¡Exito!', html: 'Registro guardado.', allowOutsideClick: false, allowEscapeKey: false, heightAuto: false, }).then(() => {             this.route.navigateByUrl('/preventa'); }); }else{ Swal.fire({ icon: 'error', title: '¡Error!', html: 'El vendedor ya fue asignado a otro presupuesto.', allowOutsideClick: false, allowEscapeKey: false, heightAuto: false, }).then(() => {}); }` ``

Muchas gracias de antemano por su apoyo.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

La validación que intentas se debe de hacer del lado del backend. Donde le envías el dato *this.form.value.ICodVendedor* y validas si ya existe ese identificador